# GKTurnBasedMatch match-making waiting until another player matched

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, game-center

I find the default turn based matchmaking process unintuitive for users. The matchmaker returns a match even when the other player is not yet found and then local user has to take turn in a fresh game after which he/she has to wait in game screen. Instead of that I would rather have the users stay in an interactive screen where they can cancel their match request or wait until they are matched (then I decide who starts first). Is there any way to do this, not a workaround but a robust one?

My current code, doing nothing towards my purpose, is below:

```
-(IBAction)gcMatchPressed:(id)sender
{
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;
    request.playerGroup = PLAYERGROUP;

    [GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error) {
        if (match != nil)
        {
            self.gcMatch = match;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Multiplayer" sender:self];
        }
    } ];
}
```